# Detecting when browser window/tab is not in the foreground

Tags: javascript, focus

I'd like to track when a certain web-page is (or is not) in the foreground.

I've already experimented with the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API#Use_cases), and I can use it to find out if my page is the currently active tab of its window. But I also need to know when my page's window is not in the foreground (despite being the active one of that window).

Is this something I can detect using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `focus` and `blur` events for this, you can do it cross-browser on `$(window)` with JQuery. Your needs don't appear to require the Page Visibility API, since you only care about if the tab (and window) has actual focus.

Comment: On my first try it seemed that ``focus`` and ``blur`` events were not reliable, but the "note" on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184276/684253) made it more clear for me what the "pattern" was. 
I've settled with that solution, which is close to what you were suggesting. I'm using a workaround to the initial focus issue, that involves calling a function (the same function that the focus event handler calls) when the document is ready.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it is the closest to what I ended up using, but those looking for a solution should probably check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6184276/684253

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasFocus event, when it is in foreground (active or not) send to ajax call to server. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235139/how-can-it-be-detected-if-a-page-is-on-background-or-foreground-with-jquery-java) is more info.