# IE localStorage event misfired

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

Within Internet Explorer 9 & 10, the localStorage implementation fires events unexpectedly (great thread here: [Bug with Chrome's localStorage implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679023/bug-with-chromes-localstorage-implementation))

Does anybody know of a way to stop the `storage` event from firing on tabs that initiated the change within internet explorer?

For example the following shouldn't show an alert when the add button is clicked, but it does in IE:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MKFLs/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chrome localStorage Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

      var handle_storage = function () {
        alert('storage event');
      };

      window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="add" onclick="localStorage.setItem('a','test')">Add</button>
    <button id="clear" onclick="localStorage.clear()">Clear</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
On a side note, I've opened a bug with MS here. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/798684/ie-localstorage-event-misfired

Maybe it won't get closed.....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Changing your script to the following prevents the handling of any storage events in the focused window.

This isn't precisely what you asked, as I believe that would require a patch to the browser, but it causes IE 9/10 to conform to the spec while having no adverse effects on other browsers (other than the global and listeners).

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
      var focused;

      window.addEventListener('focus', function(){focused=1;}, false);
      window.addEventListener('blur', function(){focused=0;}, false);

      var handle_storage = function (e) {
        if(!focused)
          alert("Storage",focused);
      };

      window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);

</script>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MKFLs/7/) for the updated, conforming behavior.

Edit: The following also works and avoids the listeners at the cost of a runtime check of window focus:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

      var handle_storage = function (e) {
        if(!document.hasFocus())
          alert("Storage");
      };

      window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);

</script>
```

Comment: One doesn't need additional variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8235434/255363 (I tested - it works with IE9+, where storage events appeared)